# Timeout error catch and display in jqGrid

Tags: jqgrid

Is there any timeout options I can set in [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) to display an error, if any delay in server processing happens, more than a set value?

Answer (score 6):

You can use [loadError](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events#list_of_events) event handle. Moreover you can change the default timeout with `timeout` parameter of the [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). To do this inside of jqGrid you can use [ajaxGridOptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) option in the form like `ajaxGridOptions: { timeout: 60000 }`.

Comment: Does it mean, that I can set data load timeout with snippet that you've provided?